# How to use ADB to select an app from the switcher?

Tags: android, adb

I know how to use `input keyevent KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH` to open the app switcher, but I can't find any information about how to then use ADB to select an app from the switcher to open it. Is this possible?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Any particular reason for using the app switcher instead of just bringing the app you want to the front with `am start`?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think this is possible. However you can use "am" to start an app from the terminal. You can find more info [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#am). It's basicaly a tool for accessing some features of the ActivityManager system service. You create intents the same way you do in java and send/broadcast them to the system.

If you need to specify the componet name instead of using actions. You can use this command to see the current open activity and its package name:

```
adb shell dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp'
```